# How to use a const or var as a data-target for bootstrap modal?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

So I am looping through an array and on each iteration it returns a bootstrap modal and button. The issue is each button will only open the first modal, I think the reason for this is because each modal has the same id, so the buttons open the first modal because its the first id. Each iteration has a unique ID, is there a way that I can use this ID as the data-target as well the id for the modal.
Basically code wise kinda like this. I know the data-target is not reading it as an id, so I am wondering is there a way to achieve this?

```
export const rando = (props) => {
  const product = props.product;

  return (
    <div>
      <button data-toggle="modal" data-target={product._id}></button>
      <div class="modal" id={product._id}>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: ID's must be unique across the whole document. Can your `_id` be unique in each iteration? If so, you should be able to use it as described.

Comment: Yes each of them are unique. Just wouldn't the data-target have to be data-target="#product._id", I tried setting product._id to a string while adding the pound sign to it so it was like this "#12345" but it still didn't work

Comment: To use an ID, the format of `data-target` would need to be `#${product._id}` so it interpolates as `#12345`. Then you'd set `id={product._id}` on the `div`. Try it without the interpolation, just strings, to get familiar with how it works.